# Grammar Precedence and associativity

Tags: parsing

if i am given following grammar

```
E->E W T|T
T->L S T|L
L->a|b|c
W->*
S->+|-
```

From following grammar i see that since + and - are deeper down the tree they have higher precedence then *, am i correct on that?
Also since this is left recursion i can assume left associativity?
Since operators can have different associativity i a confused how to tell which one has which one.
 I guess what i am asking is how can i tell operator associativity based on grammar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with

```
T->L S T|L
```

and consider `a+b+c`, which can be produced from `T` as follows:

```
T -> L S T
  -> L S (L S T)
  -> L S (L S (L))
  -> L S (L S (c))
  -> L S (b + (c))
  -> L + (b + (c))
  -> a + (b + (c))
```

(The parentheses are only there as a shorthand for the parse tree.)

That rightmost derivation is unique; `T` cannot match `(a + b) + c` because `a + b` is not an `L`.

Consequently, `+` and `-` are "right-associative".

By contrast, we have

```
E->E W T|T
```

so `a*b*c` will be produced as follows:

```
E -> E W T
  -> E W L
  -> E W c
  -> E * c
  -> (E W T) * c
  -> (E W L) * c
  -> (E W b) * c
  -> (E * b) * c
  -> ((T) * b) * c
  -> ((L) * b) * c
  -> ((a) * b) * c
```

Again, that parse is unambiguous.

I didn't do `a+b*c`, so it would be a good exercise.